# Hybrid App Error adding plugin nl.xservices.plugins.Calendar

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, ibm-mobilefirst, hybrid-mobile-app

Using this walk through i added cordova calendar for the android environment of my hybrid application. I try to add an event and get the log below.

http://phonegap-plugins.com/plugins/eddyverbruggen/calendar-phonegap-plugin

I feel like the java classes are in the wrong spot.

> W/System.err(22908): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   nl.xservices.plugins.Calendar
>
> W/System.err(22908):  at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
>
> W/System.err(22908):  at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:251)
>
> W/System.err(22908):  at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:216)
>
> W/System.err(22908):  at
>   org.apache.cordova.PluginManager.instantiatePlugin(PluginManager.java:363)
>
> W/System.err(22908):  at
>   org.apache.cordova.PluginManager.getPlugin(PluginManager.java:193)
>
> W/System.err(22908):  at
>   org.apache.cordova.PluginManager.exec(PluginManager.java:141)
>
> W/System.err(22908):  at
>   org.apache.cordova.CordovaBridge.jsExec(CordovaBridge.java:61)
>
> W/System.err(22908):  at
>   org.apache.cordova.ExposedJsApi.exec(ExposedJsApi.java:40)
>
> W/System.err(22908):  at
>   com.android.org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.nativeDoRunLoopOnce(Native
>   Method)
>
> W/System.err(22908):  at
>   com.android.org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.handleMessage(SystemMessageHandler.java:27)
>
> W/System.err(22908):  at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>
> W/System.err(22908):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>
> W/System.err(22908):  at
>   android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
>
> W/System.err(22908): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   nl/xservices/plugins/Calendar
>
> W/System.err(22908):  ... 13 more
>
> W/System.err(22908): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   Didn't find class "nl.xservices.plugins.Calendar" on path:
>   DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/com.SFStudent-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.SFStudent-1,
>   /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
>
> W/System.err(22908):  at
>   dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
>
> W/System.err(22908):  at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
>
> W/System.err(22908):  at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
>
> W/System.err(22908):  ... 13 more
>
> I/System.out(22908): Error adding plugin
>   nl.xservices.plugins.Calendar.
>
> W/System.err(22908): java.lang.NullPointerException
>
> W/System.err(22908):  at
>   org.apache.cordova.PluginManager.getPlugin(PluginManager.java:195)
>
> W/System.err(22908):  at
>   org.apache.cordova.PluginManager.exec(PluginManager.java:141)
>
> W/System.err(22908):  at
>   org.apache.cordova.CordovaBridge.jsExec(CordovaBridge.java:61)
>
> W/System.err(22908):  at
>   org.apache.cordova.ExposedJsApi.exec(ExposedJsApi.java:40)
>
> W/System.err(22908):  at
>   com.android.org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.nativeDoRunLoopOnce(Native
>   Method)
>
> W/System.err(22908):  at
>   com.android.org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.handleMessage(SystemMessageHandler.java:27)
>
> W/System.err(22908):  at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>
> W/System.err(22908):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>
> W/System.err(22908):  at
>   android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)

[image: hybrid app]

[image: android app]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worklight/MobileFirst < 8.0 beta do not have proper support for Cordova plug-ins.

As you go through the suggested guide, make sure to also review the following, providing the required additional steps to take: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2015/08/03/integrating-3rd-party-cordova-plug-ins/

Namely:

- Modifying files so that the plug-in will be recognized
- Using Ant to keep the plug-in integrity post-Worklight build (which will otherwise break it)

Comment: Thanks Idan, always super helpful.